# document.styleSheets for puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I am currently working on getting a list of stylesheets from a given page in puppeteer for later converting vh to pixel values to take reliable screenshots.

I am currently attempting to retrieve the stylesheets in this way:
`const current_styles = await page.evaluate(() => window.document.styleSheets);`
But I am not getting the same result as to what I would get from simply running document.styleSheets in the console of a regular web page.

I get a response but it's an array of empty objects:

```
{
  '1': {},
  '2': {},
  '3': {},
  '4': {},
  '5': {},
  '6': {},
  '7': {},
  '8': {},
}
```

Console.log(window.document.styleSheets) on the same domain but in a normal browser inspect console yields this response:

```
{
   0: CSSStyleSheet {ownerRule: null …}
   1: CSSStyleSheet {ownerRule: null…}
   2: CSSStyleSheet {ownerRule: null…}
   3: CSSStyleSheet {ownerRule: null…}
   4: CSSStyleSheet {ownerRule: null…}
   5: CSSStyleSheet {ownerRule: null…}
   6: CSSStyleSheet {ownerRule: null…}
   7: CSSStyleSheet {ownerRule: null…}
}
```

Any help on a way of getting this to work would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Technique I should of used was `page.evaluateHandle` which in conjunction with a JSHandle gives me access to do the following:

```
const current_styles = await page.evaluateHandle(() => {
   return document.styleSheets;
});
```

Console.log(current_styles) after this returns the expected values.

From the docs:

> The only difference between page.evaluate and page.evaluateHandle is that page.evaluateHandle returns in-page object (JSHandle). https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v5.2.1&show=api-pageevaluatehandlepagefunction-args

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, `page.evaluate()` can only transfer serializable values (roughly, the values JSON can handle). As `document.styleSheets` returns collection of CSSStyleSheet elements that are not serializable, each element in the collection is replaced with an empty object. You need to return either serializable value (for example, an array of CSSRule.cssText) or use something like `page.evaluateHandle()` and `JSHandle` API.